# Load balancing across 2 Multi-link frame relay links- Verizon being difficult

Tags: load-balancing, frame-relay

We are provisioning a 4xT1 and a separate 3xT1 links to the same 2901 router with 4x VWIC3 - 2MFT T1 cards.

Verizon claims they cannot bond all 7 into a 7xT1 and have thus provisioned us these 2 links. I thought we would be able to load balance across the two links (via some agreed upon routing protocol) with some Verizon coordination; but now Verizon is saying they cannot as they go into separate routers on their end.

To make matters worse, they assumed, incorrectly, that these links would also go into 2 separate routers on our end as well and have given me the same DLCI's for both links.

My question is; if Verizon is unable/unwilling to work with us to load balance, is there some genius way of load balancing these 2 bonded frame relay links to give me a full 10 Mb of bandwidth without Verizon-side collaboration? (instead of the current and separate 6Mb and 4Mb links)

Thanks!

```
hostname 2901
!
enable secret cisco
!
card type t1 0 0
card type t1 0 1
card type t1 0 2
card type t1 0 3
!
no ipv6 cef
no ip source-route
ip cef
!
no ip domain lookup
ip name-server 198.6.1.142
ip name-server 198.6.100.53
!
!
controller T1 0/0/0
cablelength long 0db
channel-group 1 timeslots 1-24
!
controller T1 0/0/1
cablelength long 0db
channel-group 1 timeslots 1-24
!
controller T1 0/1/0
cablelength long 0db
channel-group 1 timeslots 1-24
!
controller T1 0/1/1
cablelength long 0db
channel-group 1 timeslots 1-24
!
interface MFR1
mtu 4470
no ip address
no ip redirects
no ip proxy-arp
encapsulation frame-relay IETF
load-interval 30
frame-relay multilink bid to gw
frame-relay lmi-type ansi
!
interface MFR1.500 point-to-point
ip address 1.130.197.162 255.255.255.252
no ip redirects
no arp frame-relay
no cdp enable
frame-relay interface-dlci 500 IETF
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
description CPE_LAN
ip address <LAN IP MASK>
no ip redirects
no ip proxy-arp
no ip mroute-cache
duplex auto
speed auto
no cdp enable
no shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0:1
description To CPE_WAN
no ip address
mtu 4470
bandwidth 1536
no ip mroute-cache
encapsulation frame-relay MFR1
!
interface Serial0/1/1:1
description To CPE_WAN
no ip address
mtu 4470
bandwidth 1536
no ip mroute-cache
encapsulation frame-relay MFR1
!
interface Serial0/1/2:1
description To CPE_WAN
no ip address
mtu 4470
bandwidth 1536
no ip mroute-cache
encapsulation frame-relay MFR1
!
interface Serial0/1/3:1
description To CPE_WAN
no ip address
mtu 4470
bandwidth 1536
no ip mroute-cache
encapsulation frame-relay MFR1
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.130.197.161
```

---

```
MLFR 3xT1

!
!
controller T1 0/2/0
cablelength long 0db
channel-group 2 timeslots 1-24
!
controller T1 0/2/1
cablelength long 0db
channel-group 2 timeslots 1-24
!
controller T1 0/3/0
cablelength long 0db
channel-group 2 timeslots 1-24
!
interface MFR1
mtu 4470
no ip address
no ip redirects
no ip proxy-arp
encapsulation frame-relay IETF
load-interval 30
frame-relay multilink bid to gw
frame-relay lmi-type ansi
!
interface MFR1.500 point-to-point
ip address 1.179.125.98 255.255.255.252
no ip redirects
no arp frame-relay
no cdp enable
frame-relay interface-dlci 500 IETF  
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
description CPE_LAN
ip address <LAN IP MASK>
no ip redirects
no ip proxy-arp
no ip mroute-cache
duplex auto
speed auto
no cdp enable
no shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1/0:1
description To CPE_WAN
no ip address
mtu 4470
bandwidth 1536
no ip mroute-cache
encapsulation frame-relay MFR1
!
interface Serial0/1/1:1
description To CPE_WAN
no ip address
mtu 4470
bandwidth 1536
no ip mroute-cache
encapsulation frame-relay MFR1
!
interface Serial0/1/2:1
description To CPE_WAN
no ip address
mtu 4470
bandwidth 1536
no ip mroute-cache
encapsulation frame-relay MFR1
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.179.125.97
```

Comment: Thank you Ron for fixing the formatting... still learning.

Comment: If the ISP isn't willing to setup their end, all you can control is what link your packet uses (outbound LB.) You will have no inbound balancing. Also, what "dlci conflict"? A DLCI only has meaning per link.

Comment: I apologize. I haven't touched frame relay in 10 years. I thought a DLCI of 500 on the same side on the same router would conflict. But it sounds like I have some frame relay fundamentals to brush up on. Thanks Ricky.

Comment: You also need to define what you mean by load balancing. You probably do not want to load balance per packet since this can lead to problems like out-of-order packet delivery.

Comment: I think you need to get your carrier involved.  Let them know you want the T1's bonded.  [MLPPP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/wan_mlp/configuration/xe-3s/wan-mlp-xe-3s-book/wan_cfg_mlppp_conn_xe.html) is often used for this purpose.

Comment: I got Verizon to configure BGP between us. My only other question is, I don't have a whole lot of T1 experience. When the configuration says "channel-group 2 timeslots 1-24" should each bonded t1 circuit use a different channel group? IE: 4xT1 = channel-group 1 and 3xT1 = Channel-group 2? Or is that completely wrong and it's completely fine for both bundles to be on the same channel group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an update.
Verizon was able to collaborate on load balancing the 3xT1 and the 4xT1 using BGP. All is working as intended so far. Thanks all.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.